# Cannot change SMS notification sound in windows 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sms, ringtone, lumia-640-xl

I copied an Mp3 file into the Ringtone folder in phone through PC. I had 6 files in ringtone. But the device only shows two. The files are all mp3 and short length and size files.

What's the reason?

Am I missing some minimum parameters?

Comment: DRM protected music cannot be set as ringtones. Are the other files DRM protected?

Comment: Nope. @KolappanNathan